# SQLite database update when updating app via iTunes / AppStore

Tags: ios, sqlite

During an app update via the App Store I want to update the SQLite database file with more content. 
The old SQLite file is in the `Documents` folder of my app.

How do I handle this?

Comment: How is the SQLite database created originally?

Comment: It was manually created and populated outsite Xcode and then it was added to the bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not using Core Data or else you'd be using the auto-migration feature. For straight SQLLite you'll want to create a new database file. Then depending on the nature of your schema changes, you might be able to execute a query to copy the data over (`using INSERT INTO destination SELECT * FROM source`) . But if the changes are too much to handle with a simple set of queries, for example if it involves business logic, then you might need to write a script to convert the old data from one database to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite> attach 'path_to_table.db3' as toMerge;           
sqlite> insert into MyTableToInsertTo select * from toMerge.MyTableToInsertFrom; 
sqlite> detach database toMerge;
```

use BEGIN; COMMIT; for large data

[link](http://old.nabble.com/Attempting-to-merge-large-databases-td18131366.html)